# How to build the binary same as pkg-fetch 's uploaded-v2.6-node-v10.17.0-win-64

Tags: node.js, nasm

I need to build the binary based on Node js 10.17.0 from scratch on Windows 64.
Actually, I want to build and get the result the same as uploaded-v2.6-node-v10.17.0-win-64 from the source.
But the result was different from the uploaded-v2.6-node-v10.17.0-win-64.
They are different in raw sizel.

What I tried

1 Install pkg-fetch 2.6.4
2 install Python 2.7.17
3 install NASM 2.13
4 install Visual Studio 2017 Community
5 manually get Node js 10.17.0 source (I used the source cloned by pkg-fetch 2.6.4 's build step )
6 manually apply patch : node.v10.17.0.cpp.patch from pkg-fetch 2.6.4 source.
7 build
I used the same command as pkg-fetch 2.6.4 for the build.
“**cmd /c vcbuild.bat x64 noetw nosign noperfctr**”

[image]

Comment: Hi Zhefeng, were you able to make any progress here. I am stuck with a similar situation and need help with it.

Comment: After I tried on another computer, it worked. So I did not find the essential reason for this.